# Can I write to NFS share from Dataproc on GCE Spark job?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm new to Datapoc and GCE. In general we store our data on NFS shared disks and use local Spark to process it. We're migrating to cloud, so I'm curious if I can mount NFS share to Dataproc cluster workers and process data in parallel and what are possible obstacles with this approach.

I've tried to reach the GCP Dataproc documentation, but haven't found a clue about my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting I confirmed that it's possible to mount NFS share to Dataproc workers and read and write it without any issues. It could be done by https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions where we can add mount actions. One possible obstacle here could be with write permissions: worker processes are runnning under different user than master process, so please ensure that writing permissions allow worker user to write in directory created by master user.